# Changing font color to an article with CSS?

Tags: css

how can I change the font color in one article, with css. I have 3 articles, like these:  I want to change the font color to the second article, in the css file, and I don't know how...

```
<article class="news">
           <h2>Technologiczna osobliwość</h2>
            <p>
                Technologiczna osobliwość (lub po prostu osobliwość, z ang. singularity) – hipotetyczny punkt w przyszłym rozwoju cywilizacji, w którym postęp techniczny stanie się tak szybki, że wszelkie ludzkie 
            </p>
            <blockquote>Wikipedia</blockquote>
        </article>

        <article class="news active-news">
                <h2>Superinteligencja</h2>
                <p>
                    Superinteligencja lub nadludzka inteligencja – osoba przewyższająca intelektualnie każdego istniejącego człowieka, praktycznie we wszystkich aspektach, w tym również kreatywnością, 
                </p>
```

I tried this:

```
news active-news  {
    color: #1db954;
}

this:

.news active-news  {
    color: #1db954;
}

and this:

#news active-news  {
    color: #1db954;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to directly concatenate the class-names of the styles with dots if they are for the same element.

```css
.news.active-news  {
    color: #1db954;
}
```

```html
<article class="news">
  <h2>Technologiczna osobliwość</h2>
  <p>
  Technologiczna osobliwość (lub po prostu osobliwość, z ang. singularity) – hipotetyczny punkt w przyszłym rozwoju cywilizacji, w którym postęp techniczny stanie się tak szybki, że wszelkie ludzkie 
  </p>
  <blockquote>Wikipedia</blockquote>
</article>

<article class="news active-news">
  <h2>Superinteligencja</h2>
  <p>
  Superinteligencja lub nadludzka inteligencja – osoba przewyższająca intelektualnie każdego istniejącego człowieka, praktycznie we wszystkich aspektach, w tym również kreatywnością, 
  </p>
</article>
```

Another option would be to target a second element of a kind with this (no matter if it has the `active-news` style):

```
.news:nth-child(2) {
  color: #1db954;
}
```

Comment: Still...It doesn't work... I see that your code works, but the same code in my editor doesn't work...

Comment: It could be that you are overwriting the style somewhere else in your stylesheets. They are handled with different priority if for example you have a style-delcaration that is more precise, like: `#news-container .news.active-news {}` or you are using somewhere the `!important` modifier that targets the elements style.